# Can't exit NSSearchField after inserted text and cleared it

Tags: macos, cocoa, nssearchfield

I added an NSSearchField to my NSViewController, which is the main controller of my outline view. Now it implements next classes:

```
class MainCatalogNSViewController: NSViewController, NSOutlineViewDelegate, NSOutlineViewDataSource, NSSearchFieldDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchField.delegate = self
    }
}
```

The search field works well without any issues until I set a delegate as above.
Once it's set, I can't exit it if was edited and cleared.

Could you please explain to me why this happens? Can this issue be related to outline view? I used the NSSearchField before, and it always worked well.

[image]

Comment: Did you implement any `NSSearchFieldDelegate` methods?

Comment: @Willeke no, I only added the `NSSearchFieldDelegate` and assigned a delegate to the search field. It's very weird, I have the same `NSSearchField` in the next outline view, but it's an `NSTableView` instead of `NSOutlineView`.

Comment: How does the search field work, is it connected to an action method? Did you implement any `NSTextFieldDelegate` or `NSControlTextEditingDelegate` methods?

Comment: @Willeke, it seems I found the root of the issue. I declared the optional `control() {}` method, which prevents submitting of empty items in the outline view.

Comment: Now I need to figure out how to distinguish between NSTableCell and NSSearchFIeld input.

Comment: Check if `control` is the search field.

Comment: Oh, thanks @Willeke!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the issue was the next method, declared in the NSViewController, which prevents saving of the empty cells in the outline view:

```
func control(_ control: NSControl, textShouldEndEditing fieldEditor: NSText) -> Bool {
    // don't allow empty node names
    return !(fieldEditor.string.isEmpty ?? true)
}
```

And now it handles the `NSSearchField` events in this case, instead of outline view table cells editing.